# jupyter notebook ubuntu crash

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

for no reason my jupyter notebook stop work,   I tried to reinstall jupyter 10 times, and I tried every advice from StackOverflow(with a similar problem), but nothing dont work.

```
OS: Ubuntu 18. LTS
```

When I type the jupyter notebook in trml : this will open jupyter in web browser, when i want to open any notebook, this error(sample) will occurs in terminal:

```
      jupyter notebook
        [I 14:36:40.885 NotebookApp] [Jupytext Server Extension] Deriving a JupytextContentsManager from LargeFileManager
        [I 14:36:40.888 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/lukas/block_chain/trading_long_only/ML_base_strategy/blockchain
        [I 14:36:40.889 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
        [I 14:36:40.889 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=04fa71992a1c4a9efbea6c00cf5c24f3fad13ffc18cf4197
        [I 14:36:40.889 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
        [C 14:36:40.895 NotebookApp] 
            
            To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
                file:///home/lukas/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-4027-open.html
            Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
                http://localhost:8888/?token=04fa71992a1c4a9efbea6c00cf5c24f3fad13ffc18cf4197
        /usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py:257: UserWarning: d

ate_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0. Use jupyter_client.jsonutil.json_default.
      return _iterencode(o, 0)
    [I 14:36:54.232 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 912568d4-8186-4581-8888-87366eaa1c2e
    ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
        return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
        self.pre_handler_hook()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
        self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
        handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
    ValueError: signal only works in main thread
    ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
        return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
        self.pre_handler_hook()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
        self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
        handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
    ValueError: signal only works in main thread
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7fe118216a60>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
        ret = callback()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 535, in <lambda>
        self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda: self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 451, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 434, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
        return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
        self.pre_handler_hook()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
        self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
        handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
    ValueError: signal only works in main thread
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
        app.launch_new_instance()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
        app.start()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
        self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 425, in run_forever
        raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
    RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
    [I 14:36:57.229 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
```

Comment: I know you think you tried reinstalling several times but you didn't clean out other old things first, and so you are seeing things like `date_default is deprecated since jupyter_client 7.0.0.` indicating when starting up there's mixing and matching of old and new. Although in that case it is just a warning, seeing it is indicating you have a mix of things and that can cause issues. Have you tried `pip install --upgrade ipykernel`, like suggested [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6783#issuecomment-586597382)?